# Add custom variable/data to AngularFirestoreDocument

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I have a code like this to login user and save them to firebase database

```js
async EmailRegister(email: any, password: any, displayName: any) {
  return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      result.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: ''
      }).then(() => {
        this.updateUserData(result.user);
        // this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/projects/all-project');
        window.alert("You have been successfully registered!");
        console.log(result.user)
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error.message)
    })
}

private updateUserData(user) {
  // Sets user data to firestore on login
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const data = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    kewirusType: user.kewirusType
  }
  return userRef.set(data, { merge: true })
}
```

I want to pass new data like `kewirusType` when user registers, how to do that?

Comment: Please clarify what is `kewirusType`, what it does and where it is initialized?

Comment: it's like user role

Comment: So basically each user has same after register?

Comment: no, in register i have select input so they can choose what role they want to be. like they can choose are they student, teacher or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just fix your problem try pass the `kewirusType` from form to updateUserData for example:

1. pass the kewirus to this method:

```js
async EmailRegister(email: any, password: any, displayName: any, kewirusType: string) {
return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
    result.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: ''
      }).then(() => {
        this.updateUserData(result.user, kewirusType);
        // this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/projects/all-project');
        window.alert("You have been successfully registered!");
        console.log(result.user)
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
    window.alert(error.message)
    })
}
```

2. and to `updateUserData`:

```js
private updateUserData(user, kewirusType: string) {
// Sets user data to firestore on login
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const data = {
uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    kewirusType //notice change here
  }
  return userRef.set(data, { merge: true })
}
```

---

EXTRA:

Instead of create this data in your app, consider using [firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to create `user/{uuid}` document, for example:

```js
export const initUserData = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const collectionDoc = admin.firestore().collection(`users`);

  return collectionDoc.doc(user.uid).set({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    kewirusType: "value"
    //... your data here
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(`Data for user ${user.uid} initialized`);
  });

});
```

Then in your app you can simply subscribe `/user/{uuid}` document to get user's data. Its better and safer to delegate such processes outside the app.

Firebase function have access to each firebase service (auth, documents, storage etc) so basically you can do a lot with it.

Comment: so i don't have to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword and updateProfile to store authenticated user data?

Comment: When you use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` (or any other login method) above function will be called.

Anyway there is no way to pass the "kewirusType" from form to function. I think you have to update the user object after the document appear in your app.

Comment: do you mean that your answer is changing the updateUserData() function?